# Anti-Captcha- Erro "Captcha Errado"

Tags: html5, python-3.x, recaptcha

Encontro-me com o seguinte problema:

- Ao submeter um `form`, após resolver um `captcha`, é retornado o seguinte erro: *Captcha Errado*

Estou a usar a seguinte [API](https://github.com/AndreiDrang/python3-anticaptcha)

Código Utilizado:

```py
check_key = self.driver.find_element_by_class_name('g-recaptcha')
site_key = check_key.get_attribute("data-sitekey")
url_key = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//iframe[contains(@src,'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/anchor?ar=1&k=" + site_key + "')]")
url = url_key.get_attribute("src")

 ANTICAPTCHA_KEY = api_key
                    PAGE_URL = url
                    SITE_KEY = site_key

                    result = NoCaptchaTaskProxyless.NoCaptchaTaskProxyless(anticaptcha_key = ANTICAPTCHA_KEY)\
                    .captcha_handler(websiteURL=PAGE_URL,
                                 websiteKey=SITE_KEY)
                    captcha_answer = result.get("solution").get("gRecaptchaResponse")
                    if captcha_answer != "":
                        print(captcha_answer)
                        self.driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('g-recaptcha-response').focus();")
                        time.sleep(2)
                        self.driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('g-recaptcha-response').style.display = 'block';")
                        time.sleep(2)
                        self.driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('g-recaptcha-response').innerHTML='%s'" % captcha_answer)
                        time.sleep(2)
                        nextBtn = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@value='Avançar']")
                        nextBtn.click()
```

Tenho a `key` da API e os valores dos campos `url` e `site_key` estão a ser corretamente passados.

O valor do campo `textarea` é preenhcido, contudo, o erro é retornado (após clicar no botão). 
Poderá o token retornado estar errado ?

Obrigado.

Comment: Enfrentei problemas com captcha também, percebique ninguém respondeu e é antiga essa pergunta, não conheço essa API, porém resolvi meus problemas usando https://2captcha.com/, para quem tiver com esse problema o site tem exemplos de como resolver esses captchas.